# jQuery Mobile page content not loading on on first visit

Tags: ios, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap to develop a new app for iOS devices.

- jquery mobile-1.3.2
- Cordova 3.0.0-0

Im having an issue loading the main content of a page, the main page load normally without any problem however if i click navigate to anther page the main content of page dose not load. If I visit another page on my application or simply go back and revisit all the contents load without any problem whatsoever.

Page on the first visit [image]

Page after first visit [image]

Going into my logs there is no error the only message i can see is

1. CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
2. Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1

Just to make it clear these two errors are there all the time so i am not sure if it is something to do with loading main content of the page

Here is my code

```html
    <!--FAQs  -->
    <div data-role="page" id="fqsabout_pg" data-title="fqsabout_pg" data-theme="x">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a data-role="none" class="logo_img overlay30" data-transition="none">
          <img class="banner" id="banner" src="" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="sub-title">FAQs</div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" class="scrollable schrollcontiner">
        <div class="pg-massage-box">
          <p class="pg-message">
            This section contains answers to some of the most common questions</p>
      <div data-role="popup" id="howVacWork">
      <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" class="vacccine-pg-list-box" data-theme="b">
          <div data-role="collapsible" id="Routine-collaspible">
            <h3>Alternatives</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#xyz" data-transition="none">xyz </a></li>
              <li><a href="#wbw" data-transition="none">wbw</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible" id="Special-collaspible">
            <h3>Safety</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#mnw" data-transition="none">mnw</a></li>
              <li><a href="#qrc" data-transition="none">qrc </a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" id="line">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#home_pg" id="tab1" data-transition="none">
                <img src="img/HoMe.png" alt="" />
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I mange to fix the problem.

Apparently iOS8 doesn't support **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**

Removing **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;** Fix the problem.